# Javascript Code is skipping around randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a game with multiple endings, however, the code keeps skipping around in ways I did not intend. Everytime I get to a point where there are two paths, the code starts repeating the options over and over, not as intended. It also does not follow through the story in a linear fashion, please help.

Repl.it Link: `enter code here`
https://repl.it/@samkaraka/AjarForestgreenKissingbug

```
var plotDevices = [];

function make (b, c,  e,  g, h){
    this.optionArray = [];
    this.optionArray = b;
    this.optionText = c;
    this.storyText = e;
    this.color = g;
    this.bgColor = h;
}

function displayPlotDevice (num){



    if (plotDevices[num].bgColor !== undefined){
        $("body").css("background-color", plotDevices[num].bgColor);

    }
    if (plotDevices[num].color !== undefined){
        $("body").css("color", plotDevices[num].color);
        $("#story").css("border-color", plotDevices[num].color);
    }

    $("#optionArea").remove();
    $("body").append("<div id='optionArea'></div>");
    $("p").empty("#story");
    $("#story p").text(plotDevices[num].storyText);
//Upon putting in the following function, I could more easily follow the weird pattern that the script was taking alert(plotDevices[num].storyText);
    //One option (Nasrrative transition)
        if (plotDevices[num].optionArray.length == 1){
            setTimeout(
            function() {
                $("body").click(function() {
                    displayPlotDevice(plotDevices[num].optionArray[0]);
                });
            }, 500);
    //Two Options (A pretty big decision)
        } else if(plotDevices[num].optionArray.length == 2){
            setTimeout(
            function() {

            $("#optionArea").append("<div class='twoOptions' onclick='displayPlotDevice("+ plotDevices[num].optionArray[0] +")'> <p> " + plotDevices[plotDevices[num].optionArray[0]].optionText + " </p></div>");
            $("#optionArea").append("<div class='twoOptions' onclick='displayPlotDevice("+ plotDevices[num].optionArray[1] +")'> <p> " + plotDevices[plotDevices[num].optionArray[1]].optionText + " </p></div>");

            }, 500);
    //Multiple Options (Usually for convos)
        } else {
            setTimeout(
            function() {
                $("body").click(function() {
                    displayPlotDevice(plotDevices[num].optionArray[0]);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
}

function start (){
    $("body").empty();
    $("body").append("<div id='story'><p>test</p></div>");
    $("body").append("<div id='optionArea'><p>test</p></div>");
    displayPlotDevice(0);

}
//plotDevices[0] = new make([1], undefined, "Story");

plotDevices[0] = new make([1], undefined, "Event A", "#FBFFB9", "#EC7357");
plotDevices[1] = new make([2], undefined, "Event B");
plotDevices[2] = new make([3, 4], undefined, "Event C - Choose which Path to take");
plotDevices[3] = new make([5], "Path A", "Event D - Taking Path A", "#FFFFFF", "green");
plotDevices[4] = new make([6], "Path B", "Event D - Taking Path B");
plotDevices[5] = new make([7], undefined, " Event E w/ Path A (End)");
plotDevices[6] = new make([8], undefined, "Event E w/ Path B (End)");
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Title Page </h1>
        <p onclick="start()" class="net">  Start </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: dont but `document ready` in your function. it is already triggerd.

Comment: Your issue is that you have the click event trigger on the body. So when you are clicking the the path it runs your function twice. You have the onclick set on your path options as well as on the body.

Comment: where instead should I put it?

Comment: I would pass another param in the make function that allows the clicking on the event title or not... i will build a js fiddle. hang on